# In Rust, Member/field names of structure required during instantiating it. why cant we pass just values?

Tags: rust

```
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}
fn main() {
    let integer = Point { x: 5, y: 10 };
}
```

In above example is right way of initialization. But user who wants to access the structure, if its public, he should know well aware of structure field names, in this example x and y.

why do we need to remember the field names, why cant we just assign the values?
is this possible any chance?
let integer = Point {5,10 }

Note: using tuple structure it is possible. but my main doubt is related to remembering structure field names.

Comment: If you don't want to remember the field names, it means they're not needed. Use a tuple then. There are many alternatives, like using a constructor or a macro.

Answer (score 2):

> why do we need to remember the field names

Because structs have named fields.

> why cant we just assign the values?

That's what you're doing.

> is this possible any chance? let integer = Point {5,10 }

No. Although you can use a "constructor" associated function:

```rust
impl <T> Point<T> {
    fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Self { Point { x, y } }
}
// ...
let integer = Point::new(5, 10);
```

Comment: For the sake of clarification related to the question, `Point { x, y }` only works in this context because it's equivalent to `Point { x: x, y: y }`. If `new` had been defined with different parameter names, the labels in the creation of a `Point` would still be necessary. E.g. ` fn new(a: T, b: T) -> Self { Point { x: a, y: b } }`

Comment: Well the shorthand works in any context where the field and variable names match, it's nothing specific to any sort of associated function, but yes.